# Omniauth-GoogleApi設定でredirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

RailsのアプリでGoogleのOauthを入れようとしてます。
一通り設定してからGoogle+のソーシャルログインリンクボタンを押したところ
[image: error]
となりました。

各ソースは以下の通りです。まずGemfile。

```
# Devise & Omniauth
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

コントローラーはこちらです。

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def google
      @user = User.find_for_google(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Google'
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      else
        session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
  end
```

Viewはこちらです。

```
- if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
    = link_to image_tag('facebook.png'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
    = link_to image_tag('twitter.png'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter)
    = link_to image_tag('google.png'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google)
    br
```

Route.rbはこちらです。

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'home/index'

devise_for :users, skip: [:session, :password, :registration], controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
   get '/' => 'frontpage#index'
   get 'restaurant/' => 'restaurant#index'
   get 'restaurant/:id' => 'restaurant#show'

   devise_for :users, skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]

end
```

最後にGoogleDeveloperの設定です。
[image: googleapi]
恐らく、リダイレクト先が間違っていてViewのヘルパーuser_omniauth_authorize_pathあたりが不適切な情報を取ってきているのだろうと推測するのですが、どこを直すべきかわかりません。
どなたかご教示頂けると幸いです。

Comment: GitHub Flavored Markdownの```(バッククォート3つ)で囲む記法は使用できません。行頭に半角の空白4つを書くとコード用の記法になります。[Markdown](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)についてのガイドも見ておいてください。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/44789 マルチポスト